# Why does this method not continue to look up an index after it first appears?

Tags: java

Why does "getIndex" not continue to look up an index after it first appears?

The write method implements an index that finds the first occurrence of a specified element in an array.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        //定义数组
        int[] arr = {5,7,2,3,5};
        //键盘录入
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("请输入要查找的数字:");
        int num = sc.nextInt();

        int index = getIndex(arr,num);
        System.out.println(index);
    }

    public static int getIndex(int[] arr,int value) {
        for(int i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
            if(arr[i] == value) {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
```

I expect the output is 0 and 4, but the actual output is 0.

Comment: You call `getIndex` once, and it returns after it finds one matching element. Return statements exit the method.

Comment: Your method does return an integer (a single value). And you only call your method once. So it is impossible for your code to print more than one value.

Comment: You have only one `println` that prints a single `int`... how is the code supposed to print two integers?

Comment: ` return i;` ends method execution. And you are returning 1 element not collections of elements.

Answer (score 1):

Your `getIndex()` function stops after you `return` a value. When you return from a function, it will not continue running the function anymore!

Answer (score 1):

The return type of your method is `int` that means it will return one value at a time. Please try following:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //定义数组
        int[] arr = {5,7,2,3,5};
        //键盘录入
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("请输入要查找的数字:");
        int num = sc.nextInt();
        getIndex(arr,num);
    }

    public static void getIndex(int[] arr,int value) {
        boolean isFound = false;
        for(int i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
            if(arr[i] == value) {
                System.out.println(i);
                isFound = true;
            }
        }
        if( !isFound)
           System.out.println("Not found");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your method signature return value is **ONLY ONE int** which represents the first index occurrence for the given value.

```
public static **int** getIndex(int[] arr,int value)
```

So if the array contains the given value multiple time, ONLY the first index will be returned.